# How to save iterative models and best model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to save iterative checkpoints of my models, but also the model that achieved the best score on an independent validation dataset. My checkpoints however, overwrite my best model. Effectively, I'm using something like:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(20):
        # Train model [...]

        # and save a checkpoint 
        saver.save(sess, "iter", global_step=epoch)

        if best_validiation_acc < last_validation_acc:
            saver.save(sess, "best_model")
```

How do I get my best model to not be overwritten by my iterated saves?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not working. Maybe you could try creating a new `saver_best = tf.train.Saver()` and use it for your best model: `saver_best.save(sess, "best_model")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you're using the same [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) for both, so it remembers last `max_to_keep=5` checkpoint files, no matter how you name them.

The simplest solution is to set `max_to_keep=None`, which will force the saver to keep *all* checkpoints and not overwrite *anything*. However, you would probably prefer to overwrite at least the iteration checkpoints. The solution in this case is:

```py
iter_saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=3)  # keep 3 last iterations
best_saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=5)  # keep 5 last best models

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(20):
        # Train model [...]

        # and save a checkpoint 
        iter_saver.save(sess, "iter/model", global_step=epoch)

        if best_validiation_acc < last_validation_acc:
            best_saver.save(sess, "best/model")
```

I'd also use different directories, so that the `checkpoint` file won't clash.